# Unordered list issue

Tags: html, css, list, unordered

My unordered list seems to be going out of it's parent element and going under it. I'm sure this is an easy fix but I just can't figure it out. I'm new to html and css.

I've added my codes here in hope of someone figuring something out for me. I think i've asked this question before. I'm not sure, anyways. Thanks in advance.

```css
header {
 width: 100%;
 height: 36px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #f0efef;
 box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 #f0efef;
}

.header-content {
 width: 1030px;
 height: 36px;
 background-color: red;
}

.header-content p {
 margin: 0;
 font-size: 14px;
 padding: 7px 15px 0 15px;
}

.header-content ul {
 margin: 0;
 float: right;
 list-style: none;
 padding: 5px 15px 0 15px;
}

.header-content ul li {
 padding-left: 10px;
 display: inline;
}

.header-content ul li a, a:visited {
 color: #404040;
 font-size: 14px;
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header-content">
   <p>Welcome, please sign or register</p>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">My Account</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Gift Cards</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Customer Care</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Community</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That paragraph element is a block level element so it's going to push your ul down. To solve the problem, you can float:left your p tag in the header

```css
header {
 width: 100%;
 height: 36px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #f0efef;
 box-shadow: 0 0 5px 0 #f0efef;
}

.header-content {
 width: 1030px;
 height: 36px;
 background-color: red;
}

.header-content p {
 margin: 0;
 font-size: 14px;
 padding: 7px 15px 0 15px;
        float:left;
}

.header-content ul {
 margin: 0;
 float: right;
 list-style: none;
 padding: 5px 15px 0 15px;
}

.header-content ul li {
 padding-left: 10px;
 display: inline;
}

.header-content ul li a, a:visited {
 color: #404040;
 font-size: 14px;
 text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="header-content">
   <p>Welcome, please sign or register</p>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">My Account</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Gift Cards</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Customer Care</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Community</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </header>
```

Comment: Wow, easy as that huh ? I tried everything, never though of floating the p tag to the left but that sure worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad that helped! If that is the correct answer, could you please accept it so I can get the credit for it?

Comment: Absolutely, I tried to mark as the correct answer as I always do but an error returned saying I had to wait 11 minutes. Thanks! I've since marked as the answer.